# RealTime getCollaborators() method returning only 1 Collaborators

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to get a list of current collaborators on load and **getCollaborators()** is always returning the local collaborator in the array.

Despite numerous tries, even using the **quickstart** sample for testing purposes, **getCollaborators()** is not working for me.

Is anyone facing similar issue with me? Would like to get some feedback on this issue.

Thanks!

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/realtime-quickstart`

Comment: could you add your code? I tried the same example and was able to retrieve all the collaborators of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I'd check where you're calling getCollaborators. I was calling in OnFileLoaded, and at that point, the other collaborators aren't loaded yet.

Comment: When do you call it then? On a timer created in OnFileLoaded?

Comment: You should get events when the collaborators show up.